# Calling a virtual function from overloaded subscript operator

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the subscript operator ([]) on an abstract class, the function called by the overload is implemented in the concrete object.

```
class CollectionBase {
public:
    double& operator[] (const int nIndex)
    {
        return getValue(nIndex);
    }

    virtual double getValue(int index) = 0;
};

class Collection    : public CollectionBase
{
    double getValue(int index) { return 0; }
};
```

The problem I am having is that my compiler is throwing an error on the call to getValue in the overload.

> Initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

Does anybody know the syntax for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Is it intended that you want to return a reference to a `double` from `operator[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning a reference to a temporary value returned from `getValue`. Either make both functions return `double&`, or both return `double`.

Comment: `return 0;` would be an issue in the overloaded `getValue` if a reference was intended.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought that the overload had to be a reference

Comment: @Charles Bailey: I assume the `return 0` comes from minimizing the code to post.